# Class template with two variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standards, variadic-templates

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class... T> struct types {};
template <int... N> struct values {};

// No error
template <class... T, int... N> void f (types<T...>, values<N...>) {};
// Error
template <class... T, int... N> class s : public types<T...>, values<N...> {};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why the second one is not compiling (is it a compiler bug, or does it come from the standard), and is there any workaround ?

Note : the error is :

```
main.cpp:8:39: error: parameter pack ‘T’ must be at the end of the template parameter list
 template <class... T, int... N> class s : public types<T...>, values<N...> {}
```

Comment: It is not allowed. E.g. [temp.param]/11 "If a template-parameter of a primary class template or alias template is a template parameter pack, it
shall be the last template-parameter." I remember a question about this quite some time ago.. In principle, it's possible to differentiate between types and integers of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20981319

Comment: @dyp: How does it work for `f`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Only via deduction.

Comment: This language is idiotic.